# How to terminate route middleware chain?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple Express router setup with authentication middleware. I have something like the code below.

If the user navigates to '/authenticate' with improper credentials, I want the middleware to send an error response and all middleware and route processing to cease. To do that, I sent a response, told Express to skip the rest of the route middleware with `next('route')`, and included a return to stop processing the `authMiddleware` function.

```
let router = express.Router()

function authMiddleware(req, res) {
    //Do some authentication checks
    if(!authenticated) {
        res.status(403).send("Could not authenticate. :-(")
        next('route')
        return
    }

    //Additional authentication checks
}

router.use(authMiddleware)

router.post('/authenticate', (req, res)=> {
    res.send("You should not see me if you aren't authenticated!")
}
```

I would expect the post route not to run; however, it does, giving me the error `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. I have searched Google, Stack Overflow, and the Express docs to no avail, though perhaps my search terms are lacking.

I saw a Scotch article that suggested doing a redirect, but that seems a little hacky and inelegant.

So my question: What is the proper way to terminate a middleware/routing chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To terminate the middelware and route chain, simply do **not** calling the `next()`.

```
function authMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    let authenticated = false;

    if(!authenticated) {
        res.status(403).send("Could not authenticate. :-(");

        // do not call next(), and simply return

        return;
    }

    //Additional authentication checks

    // all passed, let's pass it to next()
    next();
}
```

Comment: That is so simple... Hadn't thought of it! Thanks so much.